# Prove for ∀C>0, C = Const and for ∀f function O(f(n)) + C = O ( f(n) + C ) = O(f(n))

Tags: asymptotics

for every C>0 where C is constant we need to prove that:

```
O(f(n)) + C = O(f(n) + C) = O(f(n))
```

I am new to Big-Oh Notation and I would use any hint or guide how to deal with such things.

Comment: $f(n)$ at least be no smaller than a constant to get your result...

Comment: As always, the place to begin is with the definition of big O notation. Study it and consider how it applies to this problem. As JetfiRex says, your statement is only true for some functions $f(n)$. If $f(n)$ is asymptotically constant or growing, then it is true. But if $f(n)$ is asymptotically shrinking, then $O(f(n) + C) = O(C)$ instead.